# array_push() for 2D array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, string

I have a stream of string and each string has a numeric value.

> Sample Data:
>
> string1  numvalue1
>
> string2 numvalue2
>
> string3 numvalue3

If it was only strings than I could have used array_push(strings) without considering any index . Now how can I do this for the sample data I mean for 2D array. Thanks

Comment: provide some code

Comment: `$array['string1'][] = 'numvalue1'` ???

Comment: It doesn't make sense to think of it this way, `array_push()` treats the array as a stack. Stacks are a specific data type, the push operation doesn't really apply to 2D arrays.

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
array_push(array($string1, $numValue1));
```

Hope this is what you are looking for

Comment: This just gives you a stack, which contains 2D arrays. I understand this could be useful in some scenarios but I don't think it answers the question.

Comment: Thanks for your review! I suggested this because he was using array_push() which considers the argument as stack.